# Is CSS generated content only for text?

Tags: css

Is CSS generated content only for text? For instance the code below shows the span as text, it doesnt create a new span.

```
.addbefore:before {
    content: "<span>dfsd</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is CSS generated content only for text?

Yes.

[pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content) do not create new DOM elements within themselves, but they are treated as if they were new DOM elements within the element whose selector they match.